# What is the limit behavior of this random sum?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let $(X_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N})$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}$. What can be said about the limit behavior of 
\begin{equation}
S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{i}
\end{equation}
as $n\rightarrow \infty$? In particular, under what conditions does $S_n$ converge (to zero?), and under what conditions does it not converge? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: If the mean of the distribution of $X_i$ is not $0$, the sequence will almost surely diverge since the expected value of $S_n$ is $\log(n)+\gamma$ times the mean of $X_i$.

Comment: @robjohn "the sequence will almost surely diverge since the expected value of Sn is..." How does the latter imply the former?

Comment: @Did: Perhaps I am misunderstanding something here, but it seems that $\mathrm{E}(S_n)=H_n\overline{X}$. Since the harmonic series diverges, $\mathrm{E}(S_n)$ will not converge. What am I missing?

Comment: @robjohn This argument proves that $E[S_n]$ diverges. But you asserted that $(S_n)$ diverges almost surely. Why?

Comment: @Did: Since $\mathrm{Var}(S_n)= \mathrm{Var}(X)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^2}\to\mathrm{Var}(X)\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\mathrm{E}(S_n)=H_n\overline{X}$, it seemed that $S_n$ would have no chance to converge. If this is not so, I will delete my comment.

Comment: @robjohn This suddenly uses again the specifics of the situation. The comment I questioned says that the condition $E[S_n]\to\infty$ alone implies the almost sure divergence of $(S_n)$.

Comment: @Did: it was a comment, not an answer. The statement was "if the mean of the distribution of $X_i$ is not $0$, the sequence will almost surely diverge." I gave part of an explanation, but not a complete one. So to answer your first question: It doesn't.

Comment: @robjohn Indeed it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be [the characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) of $X_1$. Then $\phi_n$, the characteristic function of $S_n$, is given by 
$$\phi_n(t)=\prod_{j=1}^n\phi\left(\frac tj\right),$$
so $(S_n,n\geqslant 1)$ converges in distribution if and only if for each $t\in\mathbb R$, the product $\prod_{j=1}^\infty\phi\left(\frac tj\right)$ is convergent (in the usual sense or $\phi(t/j)=0$ for some $j$).

There are case where the product is convergent, and when the product is divergent. For example, consider random variables with characteristic function $\phi(t):=e^{-|t|^\alpha}$, where $0\lt\alpha\lt 2$. Then the product is convergent if and only if $\alpha\gt 1$.

If $S_n$ converges in distribution to $0$ then $|\phi(t)|=1$ for each $t$.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding a link to Wikipedia.

Comment: @robjohn No problem.